# Trigger update results in error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger but when it tries to run I get

> The Row values(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique...

I want to update a table when the col REDEEMED in the triggered table is updated.

What do I need to change in my trigger to make this work?

Table GeneratedCouponCounter:

```
    Id int (primary key)
    CouponId int
    NrOfRedeemedCoupons int
    NrOfGeneratedCoupons int
    LastGenerated datetime
    LastRedeemed datetime
    CreatedOn datetime
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update
ON GeneratedCoupon2
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF( UPDATE(REDEEMED))
    begin        
        update GeneratedCouponCounter
        SET NrOfRedeemedCoupons = NrOfRedeemedCoupons +1,[LastRedeemedOn] = getdate()
        where CouponId IN (SELECT CouponID from INSERTED)
    end
```

Thanx!

/Mike

Comment: Please provide the structure of the `GeneratedCouponCounter` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `PRIMARY KEY` on `GeneratedCoupon2` table, also the `WHERE` part of update will case errors when you update more than one record on 'GeneratedCoupon2' table. Change it to:
`where CouponId IN (SELECT CouponID from INSERTED)`

EDIT:
Changed table name where KEY is needed to reflect fix to the problem.

Comment: @MikeRibeiro: What method do you use to update `GeneratedCoupon2` table? Is it SSMS? Do you have `PRIMARY KEY` on this table, if not create it?

Comment: I had made a copy of the real table and forgot the primary key. Thanx!